# Basic Design ruleset defunct for .NET Core?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, code-analysis

I had good experiences with the "[Basic Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/basic-design-guideline-rules-rule-set-for-managed-code?view=vs-2019)" rule-set in older versions of .NET.  Apparently it is non-trivial to get this set of rules applied in a .NET Core project.  Is there a straightforward way to do this?

The code in question is a Web API project compiling for .NET Core 3.1.  I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: A number of those rules are available with the [Roslyn Analyzer packages](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers). I suggest looking at the different packages to see which ones would apply to your needs

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track.  I was stuck because I was trying to configure analysis in Visual Studio's project properties menu: the 'Code Analysis' tab is still there for .NET Core projects, although it seems buggy/ineffective now.

After I switched to Tools -> NuGet -> Manage for Solution to add references to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers, the rules I needed were getting applied.

Comment: yeah I found it a lot easier to manage the rules by setting up a ruleset file and using the Analyzers sections of project references to tweaks them